# How to properly delete a database with Couchbase Lite Android?

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I know that a `Database` object has a `delete()` method to delete a database.
But in the case where the database is corrupted (for instance), the opening of the database fails and consequently we don't have this `Database` object, which allows us to delete it (and then create a new empty one).

So, how is it possible to delete the database file if it is not possible to open this database?

*I know that I could delete it manually doing something like:*

```
Context context = ...;
String databaseName = ...;
Manager manager = new Manager(new AndroidContext(context), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
File databaseDirectory = manager.getDirectory();
if (databaseDirectory != null) {
    File databaseFile = new File(databaseDirectory, databaseName + ".cblite2"); // Or ".cblite"...
    if (databaseFile.exists()) {
        FileDirUtils.deleteRecursive(databaseFile);
    }
}
```

*But the fact I have to know the extension of the file is ugly for me...*

Comment: What about just deleting the whole db directory?

Comment: If I subclass `com.couchbase.lite.android.AndroidContext` and override its `getFilesDir` method to force Couchbase to save the database in my directory, I can indeed delete it. Otherwise, this is not possible because "The [default] directory is the location returned by the Android Context object's `getFilesDir()`". It's a better solution, thanks!